# what are the advantages use scrapyd?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

The scrapy doc says that:

> Scrapy comes with a built-in service, called “Scrapyd”, which allows you to deploy (aka. upload) your projects and control their spiders using a JSON web service.

is there some advantages in comformance use scrapyd?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scrapyd allows you to run scrapy on a different machine than the one you are using via a handy web API which means you can just use `curl` or even a web browser to upload new project versions and run them.  Otherwise if you wanted to run Scrapy in the cloud somewhere you  would have to `scp` copy the new spider code and then login with `ssh` and spawn your `scrapy crawl myspider`.

Scrapyd will also manage processes for you if you want to run many spiders in parallel; but if you have Scrapy on your local machine and have access to the command-line or a way to run spiders and just want to run one spider at a time, then you're better off running the spider manually.

If you are developing spiders then for sure you don't want to use `scrapyd` for quick compile/test iterations as it just adds a layer of complexity.

Comment: a while ago i was actually using celery to control my spiders. What would be the pros and cons of this vs that..

Comment: How can I secure that web API such that no port scanning people get to know about my Scrapyd deployment and can not use the same API? I know I am late by 3 years, but I failed to find anything regarding my query.